# read url and then split url HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to read the URL to pull the data out of it then split the URL at `?` without reloading the page. How would I do this?

The reason why I am doing this is so that I can pass a name from one page to another to display.

No jQuery please as I can't use it in my development workspace.

My URL looks like this `http://localhost:3000/view/1?Username=Dan` I want to read the `Username=Dan` then remove it from the URL so the client can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save state of your application, don't use URL parameters in this way, store it in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

Save it on the first page:

```
localStorage.setItem('name', 'Dan');
```

And read it on the following page:

```
let name = localStorage.getItem('name')
```

Or, if you don't need it to live longer than the session, use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (it has an identical API).